# Thread.Yield vs. WaitOne

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, clr

From what I understand, `Thread.Yield` could be used instead of `WaitOne` and `ManualResetEvent` for the purpose of thread signalling.

Although I have not come across a document explaining the exact behavior of `WaitOne` behind the scenes, I assume that it places the the thread in Wait state and tells the OS scheduler to check if the `ManualResetEvent` is set every time it is this thread's turn in the queue. If not set, scheduler does not do the context switch and skips to another thread. If set, scheduler puts the thread into running state so the code after `WaitOne` starts to execute.

On the other hand, using `Thread.Yield` will cause the context switch no matter the state of the `ManualResetEvent` and do the check afterwards.

Is my understanding correct? Is there a document that explains the inner workings of `WaitOne`?

P.S: Here are the sample codes of both versions for demonstration purposes:

```
var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for signal...");
    signal.WaitOne();
    signal.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Got signal!");
}).Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
signal.Set(); // "Open" the signal
```

---

```
bool signal = false;
new Thread(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for signal...");
    while(signal == false)
    {
        Thread.Yield();
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Got signal!");
}).Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
signal = true; ; // "Open" the signal
```

Comment: referencesource.microsoft.com is great.  [WaitOne](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs,8f366147dd3f5f63)

Comment: WaitOne is a semiphore that allows one thread to wait until another thread completes.  The sample at msdn is better than the code you posted to understand how it really intended to work.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332439(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: They have nothing to do with each other.  Yield() has nothing to do with signaling or synchronization, nor does not guarantee a thread context switch.  It can't turn a `bool` into a synchronization primitive either.  You'd use it to implement your own SpinWait().  Well, don't do that, its been done.

Comment: @HansPassant MS document says:"Causes the calling thread to yield execution to another thread that is ready to run on the current processor." for Thread.Yield

Comment: Well, guess what happens when there is no other thread ready to run.  The normal case.

Comment: @user1304444: Though it is always appreciated to encourage users to look at the source, in this case it is not a big help. Managed "WaitOne" is just a thin wrapper around WaitOneNative, an external method implemented by the CLR.

Comment: @EricLippert That's fair.  I looked, but didn't look at the details.

Answer (score 4):

First off, Hans' comments are completely correct: you are inventing your own spinwait, badly.  Don't do that!

That said, your question is not about whether you *should* re-implement WaitOne, but rather, *how WaitOne was implemented by people who did not have it, because it was not yet written*. It is entirely reasonable to consider this question; such functions are not magical and were implemented by humans, so how did they do so?

That's an implementation detail and I do not have the source code for the runtime handy; the actual implementation is in a native function called `WaitOneNative`. However, I can give you a few thoughts.

First, you are right to note that `Thread.Yield` is a more primitive operation, and therefore it could be used as part of a strategy to build a higher-level operation like `WaitOne`.  But in practice it probably would not be used in the naive manner you describe, for several reasons:

- `Thread.Yield` does create a barrier, but it is not 100% obvious from the code that the read of the bool has not been elided, or that the write cannot be delayed. We'd want to make very, very sure that the bool write was being picked up, and that introducing the barrier did not wreck performance.
- `Thread.Yield` cedes control to any ready thread *on the current processor*. What happens if there is no ready thread on the current processor?  Maybe ponder that.  What keeps this code from heating up an entire CPU? What happens if the thread that is going to do the write is on a different processor?  What are all the possible scenarios involving thread starvation, and so on?
- Consider this scenario: We have a hyperthreaded processor with three threads, Alpha, Bravo and Charlie, and Alpha and Bravo are currently executing in the CPU. Alpha has 10 million nanoseconds left in its quantum, it sees that the flag is false and yields the remainder of its quantum to Charlie. One nanosecond later, Bravo sets the flag.  We just took on the entire cost of a context switch and Alpha giving up on the chance to do ten million nanoseconds of work! It would have been better for Alpha to spinwait and burn a few dozen of its ten million nanoseconds rather than take the enormous cost of a context switch.  **These are the sorts of scenarios you have to take into account when you are designing a new threading primitive**.  Just getting the control flow right is not good enough; you make a bad decision on a hot path and you can degrade performance by a factor of thousands or millions.
- And so on.

But wait, it gets worse. Are there more subtle problems that `WaitOne` has to solve?

Sure.  The CLR has invariants that it must maintain. You have to remember that **the CLR was invented fundamentally as an extension to COM** and the underlying implementation is deeply embedded in the COM world. In particular, all the rules about marshalling still apply. WaitOne effectively puts a thread to sleep, but that can lead to problems with the marshaller. Chris Brumme's article on this is particularly terrifying and elicidating:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2004/02/02/apartments-and-pumping-in-the-clr/

Read it, see if you can understand all of it. I've read it dozens of times since 2004, and I used to be a professional COM programmer, and I get maybe 80% of it.  This is complicated stuff, and if you don't understand it, you can't write a correct implementation of `WaitOne` that meets the needs of the CLR.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I tried to contrast WaitOne to Thread.Yield with the intention of understanding the shortcomings of the former and how the latter solves these problems. And you provided some very important points.

Comment: Reading the third bullet point you mentioned, besides the many other factors you mentioned, is it fair for me to conclude that my hypothesis in the question was correct? That ManualResetEvent is a special construct that is monitored by the OS scheduler so that it can skip the thread, thus eliminating the need for a context switch whereas with Thread.Yield, this check can only be done after the scheduler loads the thread context. Is it how it works in that sense?

Comment: @JohnL.: I don't know that level of detail; I did not ever come close to implementing components at that low level and when possible I treat them as black boxes. You'd have to check the source code.

Comment: By the way, I think this is the link to the native WaitOne implementation for anyone interested: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/comwaithandle.cpp#L165. I could not manage to find a clue about this specific behavior though.

Comment: @JohnL.: I think the method you actually want to look at is the wait helper method in here that actually does the logic. Note that as I mentioned, it needs to figure out whether there is a queue to pump. Also, I totally forgot to mention that obviously the CLR thread needs to still cooperate with the debugger appropriately while it is waiting, so that logic is here as well.   https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/610dbc19a4fc3747d5afebb4c94ac77c41f56267/src/vm/threads.cpp